# How to make spring boot app to work with angular 2?

Tags: spring-boot, angular, angular2-routing

I included angular 2 to spring boot app my files are deployed but the routing doesn't work this is the file structure. In node js this works with node.js server 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does "routing doesn't work" mean? What Angular2 version are you using? `bind(...).toClass(...)` looks quite outdated.

Comment: I removed that but it still not working, I want to not use hashing in url, and I don't understand why the server responds to /admin/users and not angular

Comment: Try `HashLocationStrategy` first, and when it's working you can switch to `PathLocationStrategy` (default). If this breaks it, your server needs to be reconfigured.

Comment: `provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})` is the current syntax.

Comment: I tryed both ways, in node.js with quick angular 2 startup the application works fine, but in spring boot it doesn't, the script is downloaded but when I change the url the server responds instead of angular

Comment: I'm using angular 2 beta 9

Comment: Using screenshots of code is discouraged on SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the location strategy I change it to `provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})` the first time it didn't work because I had
providers:[ROUTER_PROVIDERS] in one component, it seems like this will overide the location strategy for that component that you provide when you bootstrap your application. Thanks  Günter Zöchbauer for help